# Python pandas using data range to select data

Tags: python, date, finance

[image]

I want to select data using the date range for example,2020-2021 , each month data is a independent excel file , 2020-01 would be the first file ,2020-02 would be the second file ,2021-12 would be the last file

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.  The explanation is within the code as comments for each line.  Taking option 2 of the months you want to convert will give you the output you asked for in the question.  If you wanted to take all the months, you can use option 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating dataset with 100 rows and 5 columns, with dates from 2019 to 2021.
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 5))
dates = pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2021-03-01", periods=100).date
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=dates, columns=list("ABCDE"))

# Choose the months you want to convert the data to Excel for:
# - Option 1: all months in the dataframe
months = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="MS")
# - Option 2: all months between 2020 and 2021
months = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", freq="MS")
# Note that "MS" is start of the month, whilst "M" is the end of month.

# Loop through the dates
for start, end in zip(months[:-1], months[1:]):
    # Filter the dataframe for within the given month
    df[(df.index >= start) & (df.index < end)].to_excel(
        # Name the file, here it is "YYYY-MM.xlsx", and sheet name if applicable
        f"{start.strftime('%Y-%m')}.xlsx", sheet_name="Data",
        # Other arguments
        header=True, index=True, index_label="Date")
```